# What can i do to get the 5 highest values with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

i like to write a xslt program, in which i can get values from a XML file and transform them. in this XML file, a tag has some undertags. this undertags has some properties like a time value in seconds.

e.g.:

```
<phases ...>
   <phase starttime="201834"/>``
   <phase starttime="2018103845"/>
   …
```

How can i write with xslt the Right Code, to get the 5 highest times from the phases?

First Idea was with "template match= …" in xslt.

Comment: Sort the values and output the first 5.-- P.S. Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: thanks, what is the best way to do it? with "for-each"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, given:

**XML**

```
<phases>
    <phase starttime="5"/>
    <phase starttime="15"/>
    <phase starttime="30"/>
    <phase starttime="22"/>
    <phase starttime="40"/>
    <phase starttime="12"/>
    <phase starttime="21"/>
    <phase starttime="8"/>
    <phase starttime="14"/>
</phases>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/phases">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="phase">
            <xsl:sort select="@starttime" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 6">
                <result>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@starttime" />
                </result>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <result>5</result>
  <result>8</result>
  <result>12</result>
  <result>14</result>
  <result>15</result>
</results>
```